# Converting nested hash keys from CamelCase to snake_case in Ruby

Tags: ruby, hash, key, camelcasing, hash-of-hashes

I'm trying to build an API wrapper gem, and having issues with converting hash keys to a more Rubyish format from the JSON the API returns.

The JSON contains multiple layers of nesting, both Hashes and Arrays. What I want to do is to recursively convert all keys to snake_case for easier use.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
def convert_hash_keys(value)
  return value if (not value.is_a?(Array) and not value.is_a?(Hash))
  result = value.inject({}) do |new, (key, value)|
    new[to_snake_case(key.to_s).to_sym] = convert_hash_keys(value)
    new
  end
  result
end
```

The above calls this method to convert strings to snake_case:

```
def to_snake_case(string)
  string.gsub(/::/, '/').
  gsub(/([A-Z]+)([A-Z][a-z])/,'\1_\2').
  gsub(/([a-z\d])([A-Z])/,'\1_\2').
  tr("-", "_").
  downcase
end
```

Ideally, the result would be similar to the following:

```
hash = {:HashKey => {:NestedHashKey => [{:Key => "value"}]}}

convert_hash_keys(hash)
# => {:hash_key => {:nested_hash_key => [{:key => "value"}]}}
```

I'm getting the recursion wrong, and every version of this sort of solution I've tried either doesn't convert symbols beyond the first level, or goes overboard and tries to convert the entire hash, including values.

Trying to solve all this in a helper class, rather than modifying the actual Hash and String functions, if possible.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Before doing anything else, `if (not ... and not ...)` is a perfect place to use the De Morgan's law. You should write it `unless ... or ...`.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You need to treat Array and Hash separately. And, if you're in Rails, you can use [`underscore`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/String.html#method-i-underscore) instead of your homebrew `to_snake_case`. First a little helper to reduce the noise:

```
def underscore_key(k)
  k.to_s.underscore.to_sym
  # Or, if you're not in Rails:
  # to_snake_case(k.to_s).to_sym
end
```

If your Hashes will have keys that aren't Symbols or Strings then you can modify `underscore_key` appropriately.

If you have an Array, then you just want to recursively apply `convert_hash_keys` to each element of the Array; if you have a Hash, you want to fix the keys with `underscore_key` and apply `convert_hash_keys` to each of the values; if you have something else then you want to pass it through untouched:

```
def convert_hash_keys(value)
  case value
    when Array
      value.map { |v| convert_hash_keys(v) }
      # or `value.map(&method(:convert_hash_keys))`
    when Hash
      Hash[value.map { |k, v| [underscore_key(k), convert_hash_keys(v)] }]
    else
      value
   end
end
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you kindly. I'm not doing this in Rails, but I believe the code I used for `to_snake_case` comes from the Rails `underscore` method.

Comment: @Andrew: The `string.gsub(/::/, '/')` in `to_snake_case` makes me think you're right about where `to_snake_case` came from. Welcome to SO, enjoy your stay.

Comment: It isn't necessary to use Rails, just ActiveSupport, which lets us cherry-pick the routine. `require 'active_support/core_ext/string/inflections'` should do it: `'FooBar'.underscore
=> "foo_bar"`.

Comment: The problem there is that I'm requiring the entire ActiveSupport gem when I only really need one method.

Answer (score 58):

If you use **Rails**:

**Example with hash: camelCase to snake_case**:

```
hash = { camelCase: 'value1', changeMe: 'value2' }

hash.transform_keys { |key| key.to_s.underscore }
# => { "camel_case" => "value1", "change_me" => "value2" }
```

source:
http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/Hash/transform_keys

**For nested attributes use deep_transform_keys instead of transform_keys, example:**

```
hash = { camelCase: 'value1', changeMe: { hereToo: { andMe: 'thanks' } } }

hash.deep_transform_keys { |key| key.to_s.underscore }
# => {"camel_case"=>"value1", "change_me"=>{"here_too"=>{"and_me"=>"thanks"}}}
```

source: http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.7/Hash/deep_transform_keys

Comment: this only transforms the first level of the hash, nested hash keys are still remained as camel case.

Comment: this is ok for high level but for nested hash also use deep_transform_keys. hash.deep_transform_keys { |key| key.to_s.underscore }

Answer (score 14):

I use this short form:

```rb
hash.transform_keys(&:underscore)
```

And, as @Shanaka Kuruwita pointed out, to deeply transform all the nested hashes:

```rb
hash.deep_transform_keys(&:underscore)
```

Comment: ^ this one is best solution) Old answer was correct back in 2012))

Comment: Yes, this is way better answer now.

Answer (score 5):

The accepted answer by 'mu is too short' has been converted into a gem, futurechimp's Plissken:

https://github.com/futurechimp/plissken/blob/master/lib/plissken/ext/hash/to_snake_keys.rb

This looks like it should work outside of Rails as the underscore functionality is included.

Answer (score 2):

Use deep_transform_keys for recursive conversion.

transform_keys only convert it in high level

```
hash = { camelCase: 'value1', changeMe: {nestedMe: 'value2'} }

hash.transform_keys { |key| key.to_s.underscore }
# => { "camel_case" => "value1", "change_me" => {nestedMe: 'value2'} }
```

deep_transform_keys will go deeper and transform all nested hashes as well.

```
hash = { camelCase: 'value1', changeMe: {nestedMe: 'value2'} }

hash.deep_transform_keys { |key| key.to_s.underscore }
# => { "camel_case" => "value1", "change_me" => {nested_me: 'value2'} }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the active_support library, you can use deep_transform_keys! like so:

```
hash.deep_transform_keys! do |key|
  k = key.to_s.snakecase rescue key
  k.to_sym rescue key
end
```

Comment: Note that `snakecase` should be `underscore`, at least in Rails 6.

Answer (score 0):

This works both to `camelCase` and `snake_case` deep nested keys of an object, which is very useful for a JSON API:

```
def camelize_keys(object)
  deep_transform_keys_in_object!(object) { |key| key.to_s.camelize(:lower) }
end

def snakecase_keys(object)
  deep_transform_keys_in_object!(object) { |key| key.to_s.underscore.to_sym }
end

def deep_transform_keys_in_object!(object, &block)
  case object
  when Hash
    object.keys.each do |key|
      value = object.delete(key)
      object[yield(key)] = deep_transform_keys_in_object!(value, &block)
    end
    object
  when Array
    object.map! { |e| deep_transform_keys_in_object!(e, &block) }
  else
    object
  end
end
```