# Parse nested JSON and save it to the database with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, parsing, ruby-on-rails-4

Using rails (4), I would like to parse some data from an external API and store it into my database. For instance:

```
{ "name" : "Mercedes-Benz",
  "commonName: "Mercedes",
  "vehicles" : [ {
    "name" :  "Mercedes c5",
    "components" : ["wheels", "doors"]
  }]
}
```

I am aware that with `JSON.parse` I could create a new instance and store it if the json would match, but there are a few problems that prevent me to do it:

- `commonName` uses cammelcase instead of rails typical underscore. Is there a way i can magically assign a key to an attribute?
- Will `vehicles` be saved to the table `vehicles` ? Can I accomplish that automatically? Or should I go through every vehicle and save each one?
- Components is just an array of strings. What would be a good way to represent that? Just another table with an attribute `name`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if you want to be able to look up the `components` then having it as a separate table makes sense. It would need a `vehicle_id` as well as `name`.

For accepting the attributes for the `vehicles` and `components` use [accepts_nested_attributes_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html).

So your models should looked something like this:

```
class VehicleType < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :vehicles

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :vehicles
end

class Vehicle < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :vehicle_type      
  has_many :components

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :components
end

class Component < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :vehicle
end
```

For converting `commonName` (camelCase) to `common_name` (snake case), there's a great Stack Overflow answer on that here: [Converting nested hash keys from CamelCase to snake_case in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8706930/converting-nested-hash-keys-from-camelcase-to-snake-case-in-ruby). So assuming you have defined the function described there (`convert_hash_keys`) and the models above, your code should look roughly like this:

```
converted_hash = convert_hash_keys(JSON.parse(input_json_string))
vehicle_type = VehicleType.create(converted_hash)
```

For updating it would be `VehicleType.update(converted_hash)`

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer! But about serialize components, with this it's not very easy to look up for vehicles with a concrete component, and you're storing quite some duplicate data

Comment: That makes sense. I updated the answer for the case when `components` is a table.